# Accessing a PHP Website Source Code

Tags: php, mysql, host

I'm a PHP beginner. I usually use ASP.NET C# using Visual Studio just developing my own practice unpublished websites.

I have recently be asked to assist with a website using PHP and MySQL. 
I have been given the following details to access the code:

host: www.hostname.xx 
username: xxxx
password: xxxx

I visited the host site, there is no Log In feature. I downloaded a Platform called WampDeveloper to check if there is a feature to allow you to log in to a server host, but was unsuccessful. It seems to just allow me to create a new website (this may not be the case).

I'm embarrassed to ask, but can anyone offer any suggestions as to how I can use these log in details to view the site source code. 
Also, if there is a better Platform for PHP can you let me know, I've downloaded WordPress too.

Comment: You probably have to use a FTP client such as fileZilla. Enter those details in fileZilla's login, and you'll see the remote host folder. That said, I'm afraid Stack Overflow isn't the appropriate site for this kind of questions. You might want to try e.g. Server Fault instead.

Comment: The connection information you received can probably be used to handle the files through FTP (or SFTP). Use an FTP client to download the files to your computer, change them, upload the changed files back to the server. Many PHP IDEs can do this behind the scene, allowing the developer edit the remote files the same way they edit the local files.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can access the source code - either by directly logging into the server or via FTP client such as FileZilla - you can NOT directly access php code as its executed on the server and not on client side.

You can download FileZilla (an FTP Client) and navigate to the place where all php code is located and download it to your local machine to inspect/modify.

If you are familiar with Linux and Vim you can download SSH Client such as Putty or Cygwin(more complex) and log in to server and edit the files directly on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually no way to directly access the code from web (as there shouldn't be). Instead the usual way is through a FTP connection to the target server.

Comment: Yes, this FTP, or more modernly SFTP or FTPS. Filezilla is one example of an FTP client

Comment: Thank you. I will check out FileZilla.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, this is a newb mistake but, don't be ashamed. If you are just new at this its fine. You need a platform such as FileZilla to connect.

Here is how it should look:

Host: www.hostname.xx User: user2424234 Pass: urpasswordhere Port: 21 [CONNECT]

then you can upload files

Comment: Thanks very much for your help